Image not showing from Firebase Storage in Flutter app Circle Avatar
I am getting the image url but in network image or circle avatar image is not loading
Here is my code: (Getting URL from Firebase:)
String IMGURL = '';
_firebaseFirestore
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid.toString())
    .get()
    .then(
  (snapshot) {
    setState(() {
      IMGURL = snapshot.data()!['PROFILE_IMG'];
      encodedURL = Uri.encodeFull(IMGURL);
      print(IMGURL);
    });
  },
);

This is how I am displaying image:
IMGURL != null
              ? CircleAvatar(
                radius: 18,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(IMGURL),)
              : IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      currentPage = 5;
                    });
                  },


what are you getting in the log?

In the NetworkImage pass the following:
NetworkImage(Uri.encodeFull(IMGURL))

You need to pass the encoded uri, so it can be read and displayed. Currently you are just assigning it to the variable encodedURL.
Also it is better to store images in Firebase Storage, and then you can easily receive the url and display it.
